# Is it possible to add a <script> to the head of a page by adding '?_someTag' to the URL in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I'm trying to add a script to pages loaded into an iFrame.  Is it possible to do this with: 
     http://someURl.com?_someTag

where '_someTag' would load a script into the head of the page(another domain) in an iFrame on my domain?  For example I would like to highlight certain parts of pages like Firebug does.

Check http://johnverber.com/url.html just to see the page I"m talking about.

Answer (score 0):

window.location.search is what you want. It will return `?_someTag`. This is the code to chek the existence and inject the head.

```
if(window.location.search == '?_someTag'){
    $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/file.js"></script>');
}
```

**Edit**

Oops. I just noticed that you said you wanted to do this in an iFrame...I'm not completely sure if you changed the title or I'm just delirious from the long day, but this isn't possible.

There's securities reasons why this cannot be done X-Domain...so unfortunately, the *short* answer is:

**This cannot be done.**

Comment: dang that seems so simple...I've been looking for an answer for days.  Lemme try it out.

Comment: I'm curious how tag management sites or Optimizely does it.  They take a site, throw it in an iFrame and then allow you to highlight amonst other things.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(location.href.indexOf("blabla")!=-1){
document.getElementById("id_of_the_frame").src = "http://www.google.co.uk";
}
```